# Access outer loop property in nested 'foreach'

Tags: knockout.js

I have a nested foreach loop in Knockout.js and I want to access a property from the current object in the outer loop inside the inner loop.

```
<!-- ko foreach: graduationDateRows -->                  
  <tr>
    <td class="center" data-bind="text: CalendarYear"></td>  
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.graduationDatesHeaders -->
    <td class="center" data-bind="text: /* !here! */"></td> 
    <td></td>
    <!-- /ko -->                                                                  
  </tr> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `$parent` to access one scope level up.  So, from your inner loop you can use `parent` to access the current item being looped on in your `graduationDateRows`

Comment: But you cannot use `$parent.$index`, it seems.

Comment: However, you can use `$parentContext`.

Answer (score 15):

You can even loop through **completely unrelated arrays** using `$parent` and `as` aliasing in `foreach` binding.

Consider [the following example](http://jsfiddle.net/whQmX/):

```
var VM = function(){
    this.rows = ['one','two','three'];
    this.cols = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <!-- ko foreach: cols -->
        <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: rows, as: 'row'} -->
    <tr>
        <th data-bind="text:row"></th>
        <!-- ko foreach: {data: $parent.cols, as: 'col'} -->
        <td data-bind="text:row + '/' + col"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->  
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

To access a property in the outer loop from the current object in the inner loop you can use `$parent.property_name`.

E.g.:

```
<ul id="salesInfo" data-bind="foreach : salesInfo ">
    <li class="department">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: name" />
        <ul id="salesDept" data-bind="foreach: years">
            <li class="years">
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: year, click:function(data, event) { $root.yearClicked(year,$parent.name,data) }" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sample object of `salesInfo` array:

```
{
    "id" : "0",
    "name" : "Human Resources",
    "years" : [
        { "year" : "2012", "values" : [250000,350000,150000,220000,450000,180000] }
    ]
}
```