# TypeError: someProperty(...) is null - knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to this piece of code where `someProperty().length` is returning me the length of the property and is inside a `foreach` loop

```
<p data-bind="html: (someProperty().length == null ? 0 : someProperty().length)"></p>
```

but getting the following error in firefox.

> TypeError: someProperty(...) is null

Comment: `someProperty()` is a function call, do you have such a function, and does that function return something that can be chained with `length` ?

Comment: its s returning me the length for some data, it is just a property in an object which is then pushed into an observable array

Comment: Is the <p> tag inside of a foreach binding (might need $parent.someProperty()) ? Is this the only observable you are having problems with?

Comment: Seeing more of your html and js would help to narrow this problem down.

Comment: Is it returning you the length of an array or a property? It's one or the other, not both. If it's purely returning your length, then you don't need `.length`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us to be able to help you without having to resort to guessing at the cause.

Comment: @War10ck, it is returning me the length of property and not the array.

Comment: @IrkenInvader, yes its inside a foreach loop.

Comment: This might apply if someProperty is part of the parent scope.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989839/knockout-js-nested-foreach-access-outer-loop-property

Answer (score 2):

In JS some values are considered `false` in conditions expressions like: `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `0`. So you dont need to verify if the html string has lenght, an **empty string** aways has `lenght == 0` and `""` is equal `false`, so you just need to do this : `!someProp() ? 0 : someProp().length`, with this condition the `0` will be applied when `somePropperty()` returns any `false` synonymous, and the length of a string never will be  `null`, if it is empty the `length` will be `0`, see in the snippet how optimize you ternary in the `data-bind` attr:

```js
function viewModel()
{
  this.someProp = ko.observable("<strong>TEST</strong>");
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="html: someProp && !someProp() ? 0 : someProp().length "></p>
```